# Batch Script Help - Create .bat files from folder names

Tags: batch-file

i want help with batch script.

Example:

I have folders with names C:\folder\200, C:\folder\201, C:\folder\202, C:\folder\203, C:\folder\204, C:\folder\205 and ...
I want to create multiple  .bat files  in C:\batfiles\ that contains:

```
    bat file 1 
    start.exe xxxxx:200 C:\folder\200

    bat file 2
    start.exe xxxxx:201 C:\folder\201

    bat file 3
    start.exe xxxxx:202 C:\folder\202

    bat file 4
    start.exe xxxxx:203 C:\folder\203

    bat file 5
    start.exe xxxxx:204 C:\folder\204

    bat file 6
    start.exe xxxxx:205 C:\folder\205
```

and ....

xxxxx  are static value

Thanks for anyone for help :)

Comment: What is the reason you want to create multiple `batch-files` if you could create one? Where should these `batch-files` be located if they exist? What is your plan on launching these `batch-files`? what will `xxxxx` and `yyyyy` really be, are they static values? Your question lacks clarity. Please edit and clarify asap.

Comment: Done, it's a better description now

Comment: Don't forget to accept a given answer (click the tick mark next to the answer) when it answers your question. In that way this question doesn't come up as unanswered again. – Also note that your question here didn't show any solution attempt on your part – you shouldn't get the impression that Stack Overflow is coding service ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% convinced you need multiple batch-files, but you asked for it:

From `cmd`

```
@for /d %i in ("C:\folder\20*") do @echo start xxxxx:%~ni C:\folder\%~ni >"C:\batfiles\%~ni.cmd"
```

or from a batch file:

```
@for /d %%i in ("C:\folder\20*") do @echo start xxxxx:%%~ni c:\folder\%%~ni >"C:\batfiles\%%~ni.cmd"
```

Comment: It works perfectly. How to donate to you for perfect and very fast work ?

Comment: The way to thank a user for their help is to simply select the answer as the correct answer by ticking the grey tick mark on the left of the answer, but only if you really feel it suited your needs... and Glad I could help.